WSO2 API Manager (wso2am-4.1.0) - How to expose oauth2 URLs using multiple hostnames?
I'm using wso2am-4.1.0 and I'm trying to set multiple hostnames for oauth2 related authentication URLs to be integrated with different implementations.

https://example1.com/oauth2/authorize
https://example2.com/oauth2/authorize

The main goal is to handle auth redirections without CORS errors for different implementations.
Is it possible to achieve this?

If your ultimate goal is to not get any CORS errors for any /oauth2 endpoints in the API Manager, you can follow this approach to configure the CORS configurations

Navigate to /repository/deployment/server/webapps and oauth2

Go to /WEB-INF and open and edit the web.xml

Add the following block to the web.xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


And save the configurations


After a successful deployment of the oauth2 web app in the API Manager server, if you try to invoke the endpoints, you will get the required CORS headers in the response to overcome the CORS issues.
Furthermore, you can make a copy of the oauth2.war and make the mentioned edit and replace that in the WSO2 API Manager server to keep the configurations consistent.
